# Twython: Filtering more than one track.

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to download all tweets within some co-ordinate.

Code used:

```
stream.statuses.filter(track='Football',locations='22,70,24,74')
```

How can I pass more than one track such that It will download all tweets which contains one more tracks?

For example: 'Football' or 'game' or 'sport'.

Comment: It is. See https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/streaming_api.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track), seems like you can achieve this quite easily.

You can separate it by spaces, to obtain tweets with **both** tracks:

```
stream.statuses.filter(track='Football game',locations='22,70,24,74')
```

Or by commas, to obtain tweets with either track:

```
stream.statuses.filter(track='Football, game',locations='22,70,24,74')
```

I think twython only passes the values of track, so this should work fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, It is working fine, How can I get all tweets of past 6 months ? Can I give time duration as input ?

Comment: How to give time as input ? Could you please share your snip of code ?

Comment: Currently, i don't think that's possible. Twython parameters are based on Twitter's API, and you can see the accepted parameters [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track)